# How to write a paragraph in a JPanel in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am trying to create a `JFrame` that has a `JPanel`. The panel will have a two paragraphs on a certain topic. It should somewhat look like the image attached. Using `JLabel` doesn't seem to give me the desired look.

[image]

Comment: Did you consider a [JEditorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)?

Comment: Your paragraph even mentions the JTextPane... did you try that?

Comment: You should show what you’ve tried (in terms of actual code), what you’ve expected, and what you got instead. You only showed what you expect, and even that mismatches your description (you said “two paragraphs”, the picture shows one). And “doesn't seem to give me the desired look” is not a real description. In fact, “doesn’t seem” implies that you do not even know whether the result matches your expectation. When I use, e.g. `new JLabel("<html><h3 style='color:red'>Attributes, Styles, etc</h1><p>Some text for a paragraph, blah, blah…")`, the result is very close to the picture.